# Package gtkglext-1.2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path

Tags: c++, gtk3, pkg-config

I am trying to write an application using c++. I have decided to use gtk3+ and the gtk opengl extensions. Bellow is the build command i am running

```
gcc -Wall `pkg-config --cflags "gtk+-3.0 gtkglext-1.2.0"`   -c -o main.o main.c
```

This creates the bellow output error

```
Package gtkglext-1.2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtkglext-1.2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtkglext-1.2.0' found
```

If instead of using gtkglext-1.2.0 i use gtkglext-1.0 then this causes alot of compiler warnings.

How can i setup pkg-config properly?
Note: I have brew installed gtk3+ and gtkglext

**UPDATE:**

howbrew has installed gtkglext-1.2.0 but there is only gtkglext-1.0.pc & gtkglext-x11-1.0.pc available. Bellow is the new build command

```
gcc -Wall `pkg-config --cflags "gtk+-3.0 gtkglext-1.0 gtkglext-x11-1.0"`   -c -o main.o main.c
```

This causes lots of compile errors, bellow is a sample

> In file included from main.c:9: In file included from
>   /usr/local/Cellar/gtkglext/1.2.0/include/gtkglext-1.0/gtk/gtkgl.h:22:
>   In file included from
>   /usr/local/Cellar/gtkglext/1.2.0/include/gtkglext-1.0/gdk/gdkgl.h:34:
>   In file included from
>   /usr/local/Cellar/gtkglext/1.2.0/include/gtkglext-1.0/gdk/gdkglpixmap.h:25:
>   In file included from
>   /usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.24.25/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkpixmap.h:35: In
>   file included from
>   /usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.24.25/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkdrawable.h:35:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.24.25/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkgc.h:198:23:
>   error: a parameter list without
>         types is only allowed in a function definition   GdkColormap *GSEAL (colormap);
>                         ^ /usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.24.25/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkgc.h:198:16:
>   error: duplicate member 'GSEAL'   GdkColormap *GSEAL (colormap);
>                  ^ /usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.24.25/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkgc.h:193:8:
>   note: previous declaration is here   gint GSEAL (clip_x_origin);
>          ^ /usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.24.25/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkgc.h:205:27:
>   error: unknown type name 'GdkGC'   void (*get_values)     (GdkGC
>   *gc,
>                             ^ /usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.24.25/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkgc.h:207:27:
>   error: unknown type name 'GdkGC'   void (*set_values)     (GdkGC
>   *gc,
>                             ^ /usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.24.25/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkgc.h:210:27:
>   error: unknown type name 'GdkGC'   void (*set_dashes)     (GdkGC
>   *gc,
>                             ^ /usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.24.25/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkgc.h:225:1:
>   error: unknown type name 'GdkGC' GdkGC *gdk_gc_new
>   (GdkDrawable      *drawable);

Answer (score 0):

Brew is OSX, right? I don't know much about OSX dev, but in general the pkg-config files get dumped in $prefix/lib/pkgconfig, where prefix depends on what you passed to the configure script, cmake, our whatever underlying build system the package in question uses. Either you can reinstall with a different prefix option or you can modify the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable when building your app like this:

`PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$prefix/lib/pkgconfig:$ PKG_CONFIG_PATH gcc command here`

Which prepends the correct location of the pkg-config files to PKG_CONFIG_PATH. Where these are I can't tell you, as I know not brew and OSX, but once you find it you're golden. The files should be named gtk+-3.0.pc and gtkglext-1.2.0.pc respectively.

Comment: I searched and cant find gtkglext-1.2.0.pc or gtk+-3.0.pc

Comment: Google tells me that homebrew installs into its own folder and then symlinks to /usr/local, so check there for a lib/pkgconfig directory which should contain the proper files

Comment: Also are you certain that those are the proper names? What version of those libs did homebrew install? Also Google says a /usr/local/Cellar directory should exist as well... were I on Linux with this issue I'd use the locate command (from the mlocate package) to find the directory to look into. Not sure if homebrew has that available, but if it does it could help. Also `which <command>` where <command> is a program homebrew provides that you have installed should point you in a good direction.